# should generic super class for model be static and singleton?

Tags: php, pdo

status: accepting the only one answer choice. with thanks.

shouldn't I use static functions and `self::` instead of `$this->`   in here . I would use this class Dao as a `super class` in all of my model classes.

The Dao class will be the super class of all the `model classes.`

Should it be singleton? should it use static?

any tips ?

```
<?php 
class Dao extends Object{
    private $con;
    //will put this in defines includes file. Or user from WP.
    private $dbhost     = "localhost";
    private $dbname     = "wpm";
    private $dbuser     = "root";
    private $dbpass     = "root";

    public function __construct() {
       if(!$this->con){
           $this->con = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->dbhost;dbname=$this->dbname",$this->dbuser,$this->dbpass); //will make it generic. 
       }
    }

    protected function getCon(){
        if(!$this->con){
           $this->con = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->dbhost;dbname=$this->dbname",$this->dbuser,$this->dbpass);
        } 
        return $this->con;
    }

    protected function executeQuery($query, $fetchType, $paramArray){
        $stmt = $this->getCon()->geprepare($query);
        $stmt->execute($paramArray);
        $stmt->setFetchMode($fetchType);//        $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $result = $stmt->fetch();
        return $result;
    } 

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DAO is not the model. That's different classes.

DAO class should NOT be the super class of all the model. Model prototype should be super class of all the model.

"Supermodel" should have methods like delete(), save(), find() and such. DAO should be assigned to the model variable and used this way.

As of should supermodel be static - it depends. Most frameworks disguise static in loaders, which is all the same to my view, but honest static for some reason despised and so disguise have to be used.

Comment: `delete() save()` etc are too `generic for php` I guess? we have to write queries for each `entity` . e.g `findUserByEmail() findJobById()`. Secondly, should we use `singleton` and `statics` in `super model` or not? Ignore `dao naming`

Comment: findUserByEmail() is not a supermodel method. find() and save() - are. Wheither supermodel should be singleton or not is a question wheither model should be a singleton or not

Comment: can you give some example code for `findUserByEmail()` and `find()`. The `singleton` and `static` question was to know 1 - best practice, 2- any issues with `$connection` for its `thread safety`

Comment: There are absolutely NO issues with thread safety. As long as your DAO class is **stateless**, there are no issues at all. for the example code look for any existing framework's model

Comment: so making `self::getInstance()` or `self::getConnection()` with static methods and static `$con` is better? obviously we should not instanciate the same class every time